# Multiple select, when one certain option is selected, unselect other options

Tags: javascript, jquery, multipleselection

I have a multiple select list in my HTML. If value 296 gets selected, all the other options must get unselected.

This is the code I am using so I don't have to use CTRL when I want to select multiple options:

```js
$("#select").mousedown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var select = this;
  var scroll = select.scrollTop;

  if (select.value == 296) {
    //unselect all the other options
  }

  e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;

  setTimeout(function() {
    select.scrollTop = scroll;
  }, 0);

  $(select).focus();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" name="adrestype_id" class="form-control" required="required" multiple="multiple">                
    <option value="296">Primairadres </option>                
    <option value="297">Bezoekadres </option>                
    <option value="298">Factuuradres </option>                
    <option value="299">Postadres </option>
</select>
```

I can't seem to figure out how I can unselect all the other options when value 296 is selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below seems to achieve what you state above. It does also stop you selecting the options if 296 is already selected as well.

```js
const unselect = '296'

$('#select').change(function() {
  const $el = $(this)
  console.log($el.val())
  if ($el.val().indexOf(unselect) !== -1) {
    $el.children('option').each(function() {
      $opt = $(this)
      if ($opt.val() !== unselect) {
        $opt.prop('selected', false)
      }
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" name="adrestype_id" class="form-control" required="required" multiple="multiple">                
            <option value="296">Primairadres </option>                
            <option value="297">Bezoekadres </option>                
            <option value="298">Factuuradres </option>                
            <option value="299">Postadres </option>
        </select>
```